# sum by condition SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

[enter image description here][1]I can't set the sum function properly. I need to set a sum for all the d.deceduti which have the same d.denominazione_regione. I thought this CASE would work cos the d.denominazione_regioni is in alphabetic order so a FOR cycle until the d.denominazione_regione change would work.

```
select r.deceduti, d.sesso, d.eta, d.denominazione_regione, 
sum(case 
    when d.denominazione_regione=d.denominazione_regione*+1 
    then d.deceduti 
    end)
from DECEDUTI d 
 inner join RICOVERI r 
 on d.denominazione_regione=r.denominazione_regione
where d.anno='2015-2019'
```

In [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/izVG0.png I want to sum these data

but in I get [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBh8N.png

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'm not able to provide a desired result, i have too much data. For the sample data i dont know how could i put them here without taking a photo but on another post ppl destroyed me because i linked an image of a table

Comment: Could you post some simplified test data that shows the issue? It could just be a few rows from one table.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to set a sum for all the d.deceduti which have the same d.denominazione_regione.

This sounds like an analytic function:

```
select r.deceduti, d.sesso, d.eta, d.denominazione_regione, 
       sum(d.deceduti) over (partition by d.denominazione_regione)
from DECEDUTI d inner join
     RICOVERI r
     on d.denominazione_regione = r.denominazione_regione
where d.anno = '2015-2019';
```

Based on your comment, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
sum(case when d.sesso = 'Entrambi' AND d.eta = 'Qualsiasi' then d.deceduti else 0 end) over (partition by d.denominazione_regione)
```

Comment: as the comment on the taejash solution: 
something is broken, the result is giving me 700k when it should return me something lower then 5k. Anyway on the sum i could add 2 conditions: d.sesso='Entrambi' AND d.eta='Qualsiasi'

Comment: @DomenicoPalladino  . . . And you should address the comments on your question, particularly by providing sample data and desired results.

Comment: added photos, hope it's ok

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the analytical function as follows:

```
SELECT R.DECEDUTI,
       D.SESSO,
       D.ETA,
       D.DENOMINAZIONE_REGIONE,
       SUM(D.DECEDUTI) OVER (PARTITION BY D.DENOMINAZIONE_REGIONE)
  FROM DECEDUTI   D
 INNER JOIN RICOVERI   R
ON D.DENOMINAZIONE_REGIONE = R.DENOMINAZIONE_REGIONE
 WHERE D.ANNO = '2015-2019'
```

Comment: something is broken, the result is giving me 700k when it should return me something lower then 5k. Anyway on the sum i could add 2 conditions: d.sesso='Entrambi' AND d.eta='Qualsiasi'

Comment: It is good practice to provide some sample data, structure of your table and expected output then it will be easy for us to help you